# make mutt show only one instance of a header

Tags: mutt

How can one make mutt display ONLY the last instance of a particular header.

In many cases, such as g.e. UCE messages or phishing messages, the last (or oldest) of several "Received:" lines is the one  of interest to obtain an idea of the origin of the mail.  Is there a way of of making mutt display only the last instance of the "Received:" header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [display_filter](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#display-filter):

> **3.54 display_filter**
>
> Type: path 
>   Default: (empty)
>
> When set, specifies a command used to filter messages. When a message is viewed it is passed as standard input to $display_filter, and the filtered message is read from the standard output.

This requires some other command that can read a message from stdin and filter the "Received" headers accordingly.  eg.

```
$ cat last-rec.sed
0,/^$/{ # only process headers
    :hdr
    /^Received:/{
        h # overwrite any previous Received line
        :fold
        # read next line without printing current
        N
        s/^.*\n//
        /^[[:space:]]/{
            H # append to current Received line
            b fold
        }
        b hdr
    }
    /^$/{
        # show final received line
        x
        p
        # and the empty line
        x
    }
}
```

(This has the side-effect of moving the remaining `Received:` line below all the other headers.)

Then set it up in `muttrc`:

```
set display_filter="sed -f /path/to/last-rec.sed"
```

Comment: JigglyNaga's suggestion is working flawlessly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion, which keeps the headers in their pristine order:

```
set display_filter="tac | awk '$1 !~ /^Received:.*$/  { print $0; next }; !a["/^Received:.*$/"]++ { print $0 }' | tac"
```

Short explanation: `$1 !~ /^Received:.*$/` outputs all lines that do not start with "Received:" as-is. `!a["/^Received:.*$/"]++` is a variation of the famous `!a[$0]++` command that removes duplicates, while `tac` makes it print the last duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. May I suggest two improvements: (1) If you want to print the entire line, you can omit the `$0` and just say `print`. (2) Since you want to deduplicate only one pattern, it should be sufficient to use a scalar variable (as in `!seen++ {print}`) instead of an array with only one entry.

Comment: @AdminBee thank you. As to (1), yes, it is possible to omit not only `$0`, but `{ print $0 }` altogether; I left it there only for the clarity's sake. As to (2), it looks like a sensible improvement, I'm grateful to learn it.